# The "name.qrc" is imported But there is no background in my app

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I've been working on an UI for my app using PyQt's Designer.exe and it gave me a .ui and a .qrc file for each UI.The problem is after turning it into python code, whenever I try to run the app there is no errors but my app's background is gray despite the .qrc file(which is a .py now) is Imported and the .jpg file existing in the directory.

I've tried changing the format of the image or creating another .qrc file but it was no good.I also tried creating other UIs and it didn't work again.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(550, 400)
        Form.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-image: url(:/newPrefix/Arabic.jpg);"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 10, 81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("IranNastaliq"))
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 260, 181, 101))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        self.pushButton.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 260, 181, 101))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        self.pushButton_2.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "عربي", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:22pt; color:#ffffff;\">عربی</span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "صرف افعال عربی", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "باب های ثلاثی مزید", None))

import Arabic_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So the "Arabic_rc" is Imported But it is of no use.

This is what My Arabic.qrc files contains:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="newPrefix">
    <file>Arabic.jpg</file>
    <file>Arabic.jpg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

[This is What I get after Running my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcS3m.png)

[This is What I expect,According to the preview in Desigber.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q9Kq.png)

[This Is Arabic.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BnR4.jpg)

Now, I have a couple of other windows like this which all of them are functioning like this,thanks for your time.

Comment: share your .qrc

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you! My problem was that I should've converted .ui and .qrc to .py using PyQt5 not PyQt4!

Comment: use `pyrcc4 Arabic.qrc -o Arabic_rc.py `

Answer (score 1):

With The help of @eyllanesc I could Fix it. My problem was that i was Using PyQt4 which instead I Should've used PyQt5, to convert both .ui and .qrc to .py files.

open cmd and go to your PyQt5 directory and:

for the .ui file type:

```
pyuic5 -x uiname.ui -o uiname.py
```

for the .qrc file type:

```
pyrcc5 qrcname.ui -o qrcname_rc.py
```